# IP address range of Microsoft Location Services API

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing a LOB windows 8.1 application. The windows 8 tablet device we are using needs to be locked down by IP address to the specific services that the application will use. I have not been able to find the IP address range for the Microsoft Location Sevices API uses.

For details of the API I am referring to see this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx

Does someone know where on the MS website this sort of information is held as I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the ip address range list which can be assigned by using the geolocation services

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn175718.aspx